# c3p0 seems to close active connections

Tags: c3p0

I set `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` to release stale connections. I assumed that this was only going to close connections without any activity but it looks like this just closes every connection after the specified time.

Is this a bug or is this 'as designed'?

The manual states:

> `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` defines a limit (in seconds) to how long a
>   Connection may remain checked out. If set to a nozero value,
>   unreturned, checked-out Connections that exceed this limit will be
>   summarily destroyed, and then replaced in the pool. Obviously, you
>   must take care to set this parameter to a value large enough that all
>   intended operations on checked out Connections have time to complete.
>   You can use this parameter to merely workaround unreliable client apps
>   that fail to close() Connections

From this I conclude that activity is not influencing the throwing away of connections. To me that sounds strange. Why throw away active connections?

Thanks,
Milo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i'm the author of c3p0, and of the paragraph you quote.

[unreturnedConnectionTimeout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#unreturnedConnectionTimeout) is exactly what its name and documentation state: a timeout for *unreturned* Connections. it was implemented reluctantly, in response to user feedback, because it would never be necessary or useful if clients reliably check-in the Connections they check out. when it was implemented, I added a second unsolicited config param, [debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces), to encourage developers to fix client applications rather than rely lazily on [unreturnedConnectionTimeout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#unreturnedConnectionTimeout).

there is nothing strange about the definition of [unreturnedConnectionTimeout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#unreturnedConnectionTimeout). generally, applications that use a Connection pool do not keep Connections checked out for long periods of time. doing so defies the purpose of a Connection pool, which is to allow applications to acquire Connections on an as-needed basis without a large performance penalty. the *alternative* to a Connection pool is for an application to check out Connections and retain them for long-periods of time, so they are always available for use. but maintaining long-lived Connections turns out to be complicated, so most applications delegate this to a pooling library like c3p0.

i understand that you have a preexisting application that maintains long-lived Connections, that you cannot easily modify. you would like a hybrid architecture between applications that maintain long-lived Connections directly and applications that delegate to a pool. in particular, what you want is for a library that helps you maintain the long-lived Connections that your application is already designed to retain.

c3p0 is not that library, unfortunately. c3p0 (like most Connection pooling libraries) considers checked-out Connections to be the client's property, and does no maintenance work on them until they are checked back in. there are two exceptions to this: [unreturnedConnectionTimeout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#unreturnedConnectionTimeout) will close() Connections out from underneath clients if they have been checked out for too long, and c3p0 will invisibly test checked-out Connection when Exceptions occur, in order to determine whether Connections that have experienced Exceptions are suitable for return to the pool or else must be destroyed on check-in.

[unreturnedConnectionTimeout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#unreturnedConnectionTimeout) is not the parameter you want. you would like something that automatically closes Connections when they are *inactive* for a period of time, but that permits Connections to be checked out indefinitely. such a parameter might be called `inactiveConnectionTimout`, and is a feature that could conceivably be added to c3p0, but has not been. it probably will not be, because few application hold checked-out Connections for long periods, and c3p0 is full of features that help you observe failures once Connections are checked-in, or when Connections transition between checked-out and checked in.

in your (pretty unusual) case, this means there is a feature you would like that simply is not provided by the library. i am sorry about that!

Comment: Wauw, I'm honored by your answer and thank you very much for the clarification. The application design is done years ago by me and a colleague. We learned a lot since then :)
Would you accept code that adds the `inactiveConnectionTimout` parameter?

Comment: in theory, i'd not be opposed to the feature. but it would actually be a bit annoying to implement. internally the pooling library (com.mchange.v2.resourepool.BasicResourcePool) has no concept that the resources it pools may be "active" or "inactive". that concept would have to be added to the "IndexCards" that record the status of individual resources (in a TVL way: not all resources have an activity-ness status that can be tracked, so there should be out-of-band values signalling unknown or not applicable).

Comment: Then the code generators for proxies would need to be modified to report any activity to their parent NewPooledConnection. NewPooledConnection would then want to report activity to the pool to which it belongs, but (following the JDBC spec architecture), PooledConnections communicate with pools only via Connection and Statement events, which report only closes and errors. c3p0's NewPooledConnection would have to define a custom event type or hold a direct parent reference to report activity.

Comment: ultimately, it'd be too disruptive an addition for the 0.9.5 series, but could make 0.9.6. but i bet that it would be easier to change your application then to add this feature to c3p0, and i don't think your situation is so common that the extra work would be worthwhile as a library improvement.

Answer (score 1):

The `unreturnedConnections` can be active, it depends on how long it takes to execute eg. the query on the database. You should set the timeout for it to the value bigger then the longest operation you can expect with your application. Sometimes if you know that the value should be enough and c3p0 is still closing active connections than it means that the connection leaked somewhere (maybe not closed properly).